# How to split string into rows by number of characters in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

if I have a table for example:

mydataset.itempf containing:

id | item

1  | ABCDEFGHIJKL

2  | ZXDFKDLFKFGF

And I would like the "item" field to be split by 4 characters into different rows like:

id | item

1  | ABCD

1  | EFGH

1  | IJKL

2  | ZXDF

2  | KDLF

2  | KFGF

How can I write this in bigquery? Please help.

Comment: please do not ask multiple questions in one post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, item
from your_table, 
unnest(regexp_extract_all(item, r'.{1,4}')) item
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. How can I write the regular expression if there are 4 empty spaces between each words?

Comment: I answered your question! If you have new one - post the new question and we will help you

Comment: Ohh sorry, I'm new to this platform. I will accept, thanks again.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Substring with the Count Method, That Should make it easier to see which ones are longer than others.

Comment: Sorry can you give me example how to use substring with count method?